# error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Character'

Tags: swift, swift4

I am running into this error using Swift 4. I'm attempting to get the index of an element in an array.

```
if removedLetters.contains(selectedLetter!) {
    print("\(selectedLetter!) is in the word")
    print(theWordArray.index(of: "\(selectedLetter)"))
}
```

results in `error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Character'`

I also tried creating a character variable `var selectedChar:Character = selectedLetter` but I get a conversion error: `error: cannot convert value of type 'String?' to specified type 'Character'`

Comment: `theWordArray.index(of: selectedLetter)`? Because `"\(selectedLetter)"` is a `String` object, not a `Character` one.

Comment: @dhyman Larme just showed a way to work around this.

Comment: just get the first character of your string `selectedLetter.first!` or `selectedLetter[selectedLetter.startIndex]`

Comment: @Larme fwiw I have tried that as well and I got the same error

Comment: How did you get `selectedLetter`? It means then that `selectedLetter` is a String object.

Comment: You need to provide more code. What type are removedLetters, selectedLetter, theWordArray? How are they initialized?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `String` to a `Character` by accessing the first letter if you are confident that `selectedLetter` is one letter.

```
if removedLetters.contains(selectedLetter!) {
    print("\(selectedLetter!) is in the word")
    print(theWordArray.index(of: "\(theWordArray[selectedLetter!.first!])")
}
```

If it is more than one letter, your code will crash though, so do some validating first.